# Unable to set @State variable in swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am lost for why I cannot modify the @State variable in one of my views.

```
struct SaveableMultiLineGraphView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var dataSets: [LineChartDataSet]

    func updateData(newData: [LineChartDataSet]) {
        print("Incoming newData count")
        print(data.count)
        self.dataSets = data
        print("New dataSets count:")
        print(dataSets.count)
    }
```

I would expect that dataSets would be equal to newData but here is what I see when I call this method.

```
Incoming newData count
3
New dataSets count:
0
```

I can't use a @Binding here to pass the state because I need to initialize this view as a variable so that I can have context in a UI button to trigger a function on the view from the superview.

Comment: How are you initializing `dataSets`? You might have meant `@State var dataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()`

Comment: what's "data" in "print(data.count) and self.dataSets = data", where does it come from? Maybe you meant: "self.dataSets = newData"